# Link docker-compose to local docker daemon

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I shall run docker-compose on an Ubuntu "server". 
First I tried the default installation. `$DOCKER_HOST` was not defined. Then I set it to `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

I always have:

```
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

The docker daemon is started and my `docker-compose.yml`works fine on a Mac installation.

FYI:

```
$ uname -a
Linux my-test 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"

$ netstat -tunlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5025/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      5025/sshd

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

$ docker info
Containers: 0
Images: 4
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 4
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-57-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 490 MiB
Name: my-test
ID: YUQU:EUTG:XDDJ:F4KZ:COM6:H2AZ:LMOK:W4SR:BTXH:QEGS:6BLV:NIPQ
WARNING: No swap limit support

$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.5.2, build 7240ff3
docker-py version: 1.6.0
CPython version: 2.7.6
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

$ ls /var/run/dock*
/var/run/docker.pid  /var/run/docker.sock

/var/run/docker:
execdriver  netns

$ echo $DOCKER_HOST
unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/88

Comment: Yep, I already read this page. 
This morning I ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`:
`The following packages have been kept back:`
`docker-engine linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic`
`The following packages will be upgraded:`
`login ntpdate openssh-client openssh-server openssh-sftp-server passwd
6 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.`
Then I restart the Docker service. Now it works!
But I don't understand why…

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to set other environment variables for Docker. An easy way to accomplish this is by running the command bellow, before running *docker-compose*.

```
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```